# How come my frames won't fraise using tkraise()?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a tkinter project with frames located in their own python files and I'm using a single gui.py to reference them all for use. However I cannot seem to raise any of the frames after they are initialized, my gui just keeps whatever frame was last made.

In MainPage.py:

```
class MainPage(Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.photoList = []
        self.loadWidgets(controller)
                     
    def loadWidgets(self, controller):
        canvas = Canvas(
            controller,
            bg = "#153246",
            height = 720,
            width = 1280,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

        canvas.create_text(
            336.0,
            602.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Please tap ID on the black box to start",
            fill="#F5F0E6",
            font=("Montserrat", 32 * -1)
        )
```

In AccNoWaiver.py:

```
class AccNoWaiver(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.photoList = []
        self.loadWidgets(controller)
        
    def loadWidgets(self, controller):  
        canvas = Canvas(
            controller,
            bg = "#153244",
            height = 720,
            width = 1280,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

        canvas.create_text(
            169.0,
            258.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Looks like you haven’t signed\n  the waiver, let’s solve that",
            fill="#F5F0E6",
            font=("Montserrat", 64 * -1)
        )
```

In gui.py:

```
class gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.frames = {}
        self.curr_frame = None        
                
        for F in (MainPage, AccNoWaiver):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(MainPage)
                
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.curr_frame = cont
        frame.tkraise()
```

I've tried ensuring that the `frame` when set to `self.frames[cont]` is a tkinter Frame but it doesn't seem to work with `tkraise()`. I also tried a solution using grid_remove but that still did nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to reproduce the problem. You have only one frame, and the indentation of your code appears broken and incomplete. See [mcve] for more guidance. Also, please show what you've done to debug this. Have you verified that `cont` is what you expect, and that `self.frame[cont]` is what you expect? Have you also verified that `show_frame` is being called when you expect it to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the mistake you are making is putting child Widgets in the controller. All widgets created inside each page need to be a descendent of the page (er: `self`)